# Making sets from numbers in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have this data.frame:

```
structure(list(X0 = c(9, 13, 13, 13, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
40, 42, 43, 44), X0.1 = c(10, 40, 45, 46, 36, 37, 38, 40, 46, 
45, 46, 43, 44, 46)), .Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
   A    B
1   9   10
2  13   40 
3  13   45
4  13   46
5  35   36
6  36   37
7  37   38
8  38   40
9  39   46
10 40   45
11 40   46
12 42   43
13 43   44
14 44   46
```

I want to create sets like this: row 2,3 and 4 have 13, so they will be grouped into a set (13,40,45,46).

If any further row has even one member common with this set, both members of that row will be included in this set.

Since row 8 has 40 common with above set, the set will include them also: (13,40,45,46,38)

Now row 7 now has one member (38) common with this set, other member (37) will also be included in this set. The set will become (13,40,45,46,38,37)

If none of the 2 members of a row are common to any existing set, they will form their own set. Like row 1 has 9 and 10, none of which is there in any other row. So they form one set of (9,10)

At end I want to print out all sets.

Can I accompalish this in R programming? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there are two instance.that A=13 and B=40. So...u want (13, 40, 40) or (13, 40) ?

Comment: Only (13,40) will be enough.

Comment: As i dun have access to laptop right now, i m new to R and i feel this question quite interesting. Will try it later;)

Comment: Yes, you can accomplish this in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
f <- function(s, v) {
  m <- which(s$A %in% v | s$B %in% v)
  if (!any(m)) v
  else Recall(s[-m, ], sort(unique(c(v, c(unlist(s[m, ]))))))
}

done <- c()
for(n in unique(unlist(d))) {
  if (n %in% done) next
  r <- f(d, n)
  done <- c(done, r)
  cat("(", r, ") ")
}
```

it outputs

```
( 9 10 ) ( 13 35 36 37 38 39 40 42 43 44 45 46 )
```

---

**Updated**

```
done <- c()
ret <- list()
for(n in unique(unlist(d))) {
  if (n %in% done) next
  r <- f(d, n)
  done <- c(done, r)
  cat("(", r, ") ")
  ret <- c(ret, list(r))
}
```

then,

```
> ret
[[1]]
[1]  9 10

[[2]]
 [1] 13 35 36 37 38 39 40 42 43 44 45 46
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Can they be combined into a list with required number of vectors (2 here), containing these numbers?

Comment: It is really good. Thanks very much. It looked like a simple problem but it obviously needed expert programming skills.